# While adding toolBar on Navigation Controller Line appears on Both sides?

Tags: ios5

I even try UIView on navigation Controller, But stuck with same problem. If Tint color of toolbar and navigation Controller are same, even though line is appeared.

```
    UIToolbar* NavigationToolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    [NavigationToolBar sizeToFit];
    [NavigationToolBar setTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    [NavigationToolBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleDefault];
    [self.navigationItem setTitleView:NavigationToolBar];
```

Comment: I write this code in ViewController.m and I Created the controller in App Delegate

Answer (score 0):

have u created a navigation tool bar in app delegate.if not do it first

```
UINavigationController *mainNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
```

Comment: I need the tool bar on navigation controller in one off my projects View Controller, therefore I not try it in App Delegate

Answer (score 0):

you have to make sure whether the tool bar is hidden are not . [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO]; it will be visible by this code.

```
[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO]; 
UIBarButtonItem *btn1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:nil];
UIBarButtonItem *btn2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:nil];
NSArray *items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:btn1,btn2, nil];
[self setToolbarItems:items];
[self setToolbarItems:setToolbar animated:YES]
```